# Python Dictionary counting the values against each key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[{'id':1,'name':'Foo','age':20},{'id':2,'name':'Bar'}]
```

How can I get count of total values against each key i.e 3 against id:1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `len()` on dictionaries to get the number of keys:

```
>>> a = [{'id':1,'name':'Foo','age':20},{'id':2,'name':'Bar'}]
>>> len(a[0])
3
>>> len(a[1])
2
```

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed problem description would have been helpful. For now I assume that you want the length of each dictionary in the list keyed against the value of the `id` key. In which case something like

```
val_counts = {d['id']: len(d) for d in dlist}
```

should meet your needs. It's a dict comprehension whose keys are the `id` values and whose values are the lengths of each dictionary in the list. For your particular data the `val_counts` dictionary I get is

```
{1: 3, 2: 2}
```